# Using MS Access as Front end to SQL Get SQL Query Data to Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a Pivot Table query built in SQL

```
DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns =
COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(WBName)
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT WBName
FROM BarCodesBetweenDates
WHERE SiteID = 58
) AS B

DECLARE @SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT Description, ' + @Columns + '
FROM
(SELECT S.siteID, b.SiteName, B.WBName, B.PN, B.Description,
SUM(B.Quant) AS Expr1
FROM Site S INNER JOIN
BarCodesBetweenDates B ON s.SiteName = B.SiteName
WHERE S.SiteID = 58
GROUP BY B.SiteName, B.WBName, B.PN, B.Description, s.SiteID
) AS PivotData
PIVOT
(
COUNT(Expr1)
FOR WBName IN (' + @Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
ORDER BY Description'
select @SQL
exec (@SQL)
```

This is returning exactly what my ultimate client wants.

I am using Access as the front end interface to SQL.

Now in Access I want to run this SQL Query, and get the records and send out to Excel for emailing to the client, after I look it over.  I am not sure how to do this.  Do I use a command function or some other way to send this to SQL from access or do I save it as a query or view or... in SQL and then call that from Access?

Comment: If you paste the above code you have right into a pass-though query, then what you posted should run fine. Just cut+paste what you have above into a access query and run it. It should work just fine. Remember, anything that you can type into a t-sql session on SQL server can be typed into a access pass-though query and will run as if you typed it into the sql server as you have above.  The resulting code you thus have above will look like and act like any other query - including if you use it for a export to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code into a stored procedure in SQL Server. Remove `select @SQL`.

Run the stored procedure from Access (e.g. with a Pass-Through query with `ReturnsRecords = True`).

And please, *please*, stop calling SQL Server "SQL". SQL is a language.

Comment: Thanks Andre.  I didn't realise it would run as SP.